# In ember, how to change values of checkboxes based on another

Tags: ember.js

I have four checkbox and I want to check automatically checkbox with id = 2 if checkbox with id = 4 is checked.

I did the following but did not get the output. Could someone help me with this.

```
{#each category in checkboxList}}
            {{input id = category.CHECKBOX_ID type="checkbox" checked=category.IS_CHECKED}}
            {{#if category.CHECKBOX_ID == 4 && category.IS_CHECKED == true}}
                {{action 'CheckSize'}}
            {{/if}}
```

The checkboxList is

```
[
   {"IS_CHECKED":false,"CHECKBOX_ID":1}, 
   {"IS_CHECKED":false,"CHECKBOX_ID":2},
   {"IS_CHECKED":true,"CHECKBOX_ID":3},
   {"IS_CHECKED":false,"CHECKBOX_ID":4}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to manage the state of the checkboxes separately.

Here is an example I did for another SO question that had a similar problem to solve:

https://ember-twiddle.com/468a737efbbf447966dd83ac734f62ad

The gist of it is
we use a single action in response to a click of any checkbox:

```
  @action
  toggleChecked(id) {
    const newTree = check(this.options, id);

    this.set('options', newTree);
  }
```

In this example (taken from the ember-twiddle),  all of the logic is extracted to a pure-function named `check`.

Check itself is pretty involved, but because the application logic is different between that example and the problem you've run in to, I'll just show the entry point function:

```
export function check(tree, id, transform = toggle) {
  if (tree === undefined) return undefined;

  if (Array.isArray(tree)) {
    return tree.map(t => check(t, id, transform));
  } 

  if (tree.id === id || id === 'all') {
    return checkNode(tree, id, transform);
  }

  if (tree.children) {
    return checkChildren(tree, id, transform);
  }

  return tree;
}
```

This is just an example of how you can immutably modify the representation of all checkboxes by using a pure function. Your logic may vary.

Hope this helps :)